# Are there any files inside /usr/share/scripts after an elementary installation?

Tags: system-installation

I might have destroyed files inside /usr/share/scripts but I assume that this folder is empty after an installation. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my recent Elementary OS 5.0 install, there is no /usr/share/scripts. I'd suggest looking into what package provides that folder to attempt to determine if anything is missing.

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/scripts
dpkg --verify $packagename
```

Source https://serverfault.com/a/627436/502732

> ```
>  -V, --verify [package-name...]
>       Verifies  the integrity of package-name or all packages if omit‐
>       ted, by comparing information from the installed paths with  the
>       database metadata.
>
>       The output format is selectable with the --verify-format option,
>       which by default uses the rpm format, but that might  change  in
>       the  future,  and  as  such programs parsing this command output
>       should be explicit about the format they expect.
> ```